# Is there any way to use redux toolkit inside getStaticProps in Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, redux-toolkit

I get the data when I use `useEffect` instead of `getStaticProps`. But in `getStaticProps` it's showing that hooks can only be use in functional component.

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import Image from 'next/image'
import Sidebar from '../components/Sidebar'
import styles from "../styles/Home.module.css"
import CssBaseline from '@mui/material/CssBaseline'
import Navbar from '../components/Navbar'
import Mainbody from '../components/Mainbodi'
import { useGetCryptosQuery } from '../services/CryptoApi'

export default function Homee({res}) {
   console.log(res);
   return (
      <div>
         <div className={styles.container}>
            <CssBaseline />
            <Sidebar/>
            <div className={styles.bodi}>
               <Navbar/>
               <Mainbody/>
            </div>
         </div>
       </div>
   )
}

export const getStaticProps = async() => {
   const {data, isFetching} = await useGetCryptosQuery()
   return {
      props: {
         res: data.data.coins
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: `https://www.merixstudio.com/blog/introduction-using-redux-toolkit-nextjs-and-typescript/`

Answer (score 6):

With the release of RTK query version 1.7, support for SSR is available. Although, according to the [official docs](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/server-side-rendering#server-side-rendering-with-nextjs), you need to setup [next-redux-wrapper](https://github.com/kirill-konshin/next-redux-wrapper) first.

Answer (score 4):

At the moment, using RTK Query with Next is only possible in non-SSR-Scenarios. That will change with RTK version 1.7.

See https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/pull/1277

You can use the rest of RTK as you want with Next.